# Trying to build a cognitive bot using IBM's Watson Knowledge Studio and API's

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-dialog, watson

I am trying to build a Cognitive bot , I have trained a very basic model using IBM Watson's Knowledge Studio and is ready for deployment.

I am also using IBM's Virtual Agent for the 'Conversational' part as it seems to cover much of the initial heavy lifting.

I am looking to integrate or leverage the trained models (from Watson Knowledge Studio) to the Virtual agent? I see that trained models can be deployed to 'Alchemy' API's but still am trying figure out and see how it would fit in the puzzle. Help?

Answer (score 1):

Watson Knowledge Studio (WKS) is used to create a custom model to use with Watson NLU and/or Watson Discovery service. In your case, it would be WKS -> NLU -> Conversation.

After annotating and training, you can deploy a custom machine learning model to NLU and/or Discovery. More detail on adding the custom model can be found in the NLU documentation: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/#entities

Finally, here's an example of using NLU with Conversation: https://developer.ibm.com/dwblog/2017/chatbot-watson-conversation-natural-language-understanding-nlu/